# How to specify url for ajax call in wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use ajax form submit in a plugin, the submitted data will
be processed by a script saved as handler.php in the plugins folder,
how do  I specify this in the jquery script, ordinarily something like
`url: handler.php`, but within a plugin, that might not work.

Comment: Have you read the WP Codex on [Using Ajax in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)?

Comment: Yes, I have read that